# Extremely slow deserialization for large documents with the MongoDB C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using 10 threads to do find-and-modify on large documents (one document at a time on each thread). The documents are about 600kB each and contain each a 10,000 elements array. The client and the MongoDB server are on the same LAN in a datacenter and are connected via a very fast connection. The client runs on small machine (CPU is fairly slow, 768 MB of RAM).

The problem is that every find-and-modify operation is extremely slow.

For example here is the timeline of an operation:

- 11:56:04: Calling FindAndModify on the client.
- 12:05:59: The operation is logged on the server ("responseLength" : 682598, "millis" : 7), so supposedly the server returns almost immediately.
- 12:38:39: FindAndModify returns on the client.

The CPU usage on the machine is only 10-20%, but the memory seems to be running low. The available bytes performance counter is around 40 MB, and the Private Bytes of the process that is calling MongoDB is 800 MB (which is more than the physical RAM on the machine). Also the Page/sec performance counter is hovering around 4,000.

My theory is that it took 33 minutes for the driver to deserialize the document, and that could be because the OS is swapping due to high memory usage caused by the deserialization of the large documents into CLR objects. Still, this does not really explain why it took 10 minutes between the call to FindAndModify and the server side execution.

How likely is it that this is the case? Do you have another theory? How can I verify this is the case?